# How to parse JSON with nested Objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I have used JSON parsing for so many times.But currently I have got one which has a very different structure. This JSON response  is having nexted JsonObjects and JsonArrays.

I have tried Jackson, GSON but unable to do it, please someone help on this,

Here's the json response

```
{"web-app": {
  "servlet": [   
    {
      "servlet-name": "cofaxCDS",
      "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cds.CDSServlet",
      "init-param": {
        "configGlossary:installationAt": "Philadelphia, PA",
        "configGlossary:adminEmail": "ksm@pobox.com",
        "configGlossary:poweredBy": "Cofax",
        "configGlossary:poweredByIcon": "/images/cofax.gif",
        "configGlossary:staticPath": "/content/static",
        "templateProcessorClass": "org.cofax.WysiwygTemplate",
        "templateLoaderClass": "org.cofax.FilesTemplateLoader",
        "templatePath": "templates",
        "templateOverridePath": "",
        "defaultListTemplate": "listTemplate.htm",
        "defaultFileTemplate": "articleTemplate.htm",
        "useJSP": false,
        "jspListTemplate": "listTemplate.jsp",
        "jspFileTemplate": "articleTemplate.jsp",
        "cachePackageTagsTrack": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsStore": 200,
        "cachePackageTagsRefresh": 60,
        "cacheTemplatesTrack": 100,
        "cacheTemplatesStore": 50,
        "cacheTemplatesRefresh": 15,
        "cachePagesTrack": 200,
        "cachePagesStore": 100,
        "cachePagesRefresh": 10,
        "cachePagesDirtyRead": 10,
        "searchEngineListTemplate": "forSearchEnginesList.htm",
        "searchEngineFileTemplate": "forSearchEngines.htm",
        "searchEngineRobotsDb": "WEB-INF/robots.db",
        "useDataStore": true,
        "dataStoreClass": "org.cofax.SqlDataStore",
        "redirectionClass": "org.cofax.SqlRedirection",
        "dataStoreName": "cofax",
        "dataStoreDriver": "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver",
        "dataStoreUrl": "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon",
        "dataStoreUser": "sa",
        "dataStorePassword": "dataStoreTestQuery",
        "dataStoreTestQuery": "SET NOCOUNT ON;select test='test';",
        "dataStoreLogFile": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/datastore.log",
        "dataStoreInitConns": 10,
        "dataStoreMaxConns": 100,
        "dataStoreConnUsageLimit": 100,
        "dataStoreLogLevel": "debug",
        "maxUrlLength": 500}},
    {
      "servlet-name": "cofaxEmail",
      "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cds.EmailServlet",
      "init-param": {
      "mailHost": "mail1",
      "mailHostOverride": "mail2"}},
    {
      "servlet-name": "cofaxAdmin",
      "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cds.AdminServlet"},

    {
      "servlet-name": "fileServlet",
      "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cds.FileServlet"},
    {
      "servlet-name": "cofaxTools",
      "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cms.CofaxToolsServlet",
      "init-param": {
        "templatePath": "toolstemplates/",
        "log": 1,
        "logLocation": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/CofaxTools.log",
        "logMaxSize": "",
        "dataLog": 1,
        "dataLogLocation": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/dataLog.log",
        "dataLogMaxSize": "",
        "removePageCache": "/content/admin/remove?cache=pages&id=",
        "removeTemplateCache": "/content/admin/remove?cache=templates&id=",
        "fileTransferFolder": "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/content/fileTransferFolder",
        "lookInContext": 1,
        "adminGroupID": 4,
        "betaServer": true}}],
  "servlet-mapping": {
    "cofaxCDS": "/",
    "cofaxEmail": "/cofaxutil/aemail/*",
    "cofaxAdmin": "/admin/*",
    "fileServlet": "/static/*",
    "cofaxTools": "/tools/*"},

  "taglib": {
    "taglib-uri": "cofax.tld",
    "taglib-location": "/WEB-INF/tlds/cofax.tld"}}}
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample code on how you are trying to parse the json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect when you are dealing with a (nested) Object using `JsonNode#isObject`.

```
public static void printAll(JsonNode node) {
     Iterator<String> fieldNames = node.getFieldNames();
     while(fieldNames.hasNext()){
         String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
         JsonNode fieldValue = node.get(fieldName);
         if (fieldValue.isObject()) {
            System.out.println(fieldName + " :");
            printAll(fieldValue);
         } else {
            String value = fieldValue.asText();
            System.out.println(fieldName + " : " + value);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GSON properly handles nested objects if the field types are set correctly. No extra code is needed. Take a look at the [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types)

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Nested objects in Java are parsed as `String`. So you have to parse them explicitly.</strike>

Sorry, here is some working example using org.json:

```
import org.json.*;

// { "key1": "value1", { "key11": "value11", "key12": 12 } }
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"key1\":\"value1\",{\"key11\":\"value11\",\"key12\":12}}");
int value12 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("key1").getJSONObject("key12");
```